# List items to be same width with background image

Tags: html, css

Any suggestions for this one?

I've added a background image of an arrow for any list item that has a drop down with the class of 'dropable' now because of this the list items are no longer evenly spaced to account for the added arrow, any suggestion on how to solve this as had no success so far.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/GJezQX?editors=110

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropable"><a href="#">WordPress</a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          </ul>        
        </li>
        <li class="dropable"><a href="#">Web Design</a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

body {
    background: #212121;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #454545;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

nav { 
    margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;    
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 56px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover { 
    background-color: #000000; 
}

nav > ul > li {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ijNENpN.png) no-repeat left 50%;     
}

nav > ul > li:first-child {
  background: none;
}

nav li:hover + li {
    background-image: none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #666;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 56px;
  background-color: #666;
}

nav ul ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
    width: 270px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  line-height: 42px;
}

nav li.dropable a {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/5Clqhz5.png) no-repeat 93% center; 
}

nav li.dropable li a {
  background-image: none;
}

nav li.dropable li a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

/*
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
*/
```

Cheers

Nick

Comment: can you some example screen? What exactly look like?

Comment: It's on the CodePen buddy.

Comment: i have no clue what you exactly mean. in chrome the list items are evenly spaced. Can you please tell exactly what you mean?

Comment: Everything seems to be okay in my screen, where is the issue ??

Comment: If you mean that the dropable (sic) items look as if their right margins are smaller, just give them larger right margins in the css. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVvVyy?editors=110

Comment: The spacing to the right of the arrow is narrower than on the left.

Comment: @q0re Nope. The arrows are not part of the content, just a visual indication that the menu items will behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using images for caret, I would suggest using fonts from font-awesome.

This works pretty good

```css
/* CSS Document */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

body {
 background: #212121;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #454545;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1000px;
}

nav { 
 margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}
 
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 20px; 
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 56px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

nav > ul > li {
 background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ijNENpN.png) no-repeat left 50%;  
}

nav > ul > li:first-child {
  background: none;
}

nav li:hover + li {
  background-image: none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #666;
}
 
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 56px;
  background-color: #666;
}

nav ul ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
 width: 270px;
 float: none;
 display: list-item;
 position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  line-height: 42px;
}

nav ul > li.dropable > a:after {
/*  display:inline;
  content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";*/
/*  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/5Clqhz5.png) no-repeat center center;*/
}

nav li.dropable li a {
  background-image: none;
}

nav li.dropable li a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

/*
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropable"><a href="#">WordPress&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          </ul>        
        </li>
        <li class="dropable"><a href="#">Web Design&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good work dude, also worked out another fix but this is great too :D Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of the `:after` pseudo class in CSS. The margins become evenly spaced and you forgo having to put the image into the navigation unnecessarily.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbQbaX?editors=110)

```
nav ul > li.dropable > a:after {
  display:inline;
  content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/5Clqhz5.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, cheers anyway.

I did this:

```
nav li.dropable a {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/5Clqhz5.png) no-repeat right 20px center ;
  padding-right: 34px;
}
```